# I want to show a first category product when i reload my page using laravel?

Tags: laravel

currently when i click to any category related to product is showing perfectly but i need to show first category product when i reload my page first time Does anyone have an idea please help me thanks.

**Controller**

```
 public function getproduct(Request $request)
    {
         $category_id = $request->data;
    if ($category_id) {
        $product = Product::with('productColorGallary')->whereHas('productCategory', function (Builder $query) use ($category_id) {
            $query->where('mf_product_category_id', $category_id);
        })->get();
    } else {
        $product = Product::with('productColorGallary')->get();
    }
        $data = [

            'products' => $product
        ];

        return response()->json($data, 200);
    }
```

**jquery script**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.productcategory').click(function () {
      let url = "{{route('products.getproduct')}}";
      let path = '{{config('wall_master_furishing.file_url')}}';
      axios.get(url, {
      params:{
        data: $(this).data('id'),
      }
      }).then((res)=>{
        let product =res.data.products;
        $('#product').html("");
        product.forEach(element => {
          console.log(element);
          $('#product').append(
          `<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6">
            <div class="wallprodCard">
            <div class="prodcardImage">
            <img src="${path}${element.product_color_gallary.featured_image}" alt="">
            <a class="prodcardFancy" href="${path}${element.product_color_gallary.featured_image}" data-fancybox="images" data-caption="Flooring">
                <i class="fa fa-search-plus">
                </i>
            </a>
            </div>
            <div class="prodcardDescp">
            <a href="{{url('')}}/wallpaper-details">
                <h4 class="prodcardtitle">${element.name}
                </h4>
            </a>
            <p class="text">${element.description}
            </p>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          `);
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: where is error .? and what u have tried so far ?

Comment: i have no error but problem is that i want to show first category product when i reload my page

Comment: use `axios` request on document ready inside script and get first category products or pass data from controller on page render ``..,compact('data'));

Comment: currently i have all products of all category when page reload